# My touchpad stops responding for exactly one second after I press a key

Tags: windows, drivers, mouse, touchpad, windows-11

Okay, this is a really interesting issue... I just bought a new (Windows 11) laptop and it had that all-too-annoying "palm protection" setting or whatnot, the setting that locks up the touchpad every time you press a key. Okay, that was normal, I'm used to that, it's plagued my previous 2 PCs as well and I knew how to turn it off by now. So I went through Windows Touchpad settings and disabled the palm checking, and that fixed it!

Or so I thought... Now I have this extremely annoying issue where if I'm moving my mouse and I press a key the mouse will NOT lock up, which is great! But if I'm *not* moving the mouse and I press a key, then my mouse will become dead for exactly one second. For example, if I type in an input field and then try to move my mouse to another input, it will simply not move and I have to sit and wait for an entire second before I can try again.

I'm a programmer, and this is a HUGE issue for me, as I type and move my mouse pretty much constantly, like 5 times a minute. Waiting for one second 5 times every minute is an 8.3% reduction in productivity, not to mention it's just straight up hair-pulling obnoxious.

Now, in the past when I've had similar issues I've opened up my Registry Editor and changed some Synaptics entries... Well, THIS NEW LAPTOP DOESN'T USE SYNAPTICS OR ELAN DRIVERS, it uses "Windows Precision Touchpad Drivers"

I can't find very much information about these "Precision Drivers" online, but from what I have found it seems that I can't fix this issue... I've found countless articles of solutions involving changing Synaptics/Elan settings, BUT I DON'T HAVE ANY OF THESE SETTINGS. I've been at this for over 10 hours over the last 2 days and at this point I'm literally considering sending this laptop back, I can't handle this.

I've tried reinstalling my touchpad driver, didn't fix it. I've tried replacing it with an Elan driver, had no effect. I tried the same for Synaptics, still nothing. I installed third-party control panels off the Microsoft Store, but all the settings were greyed out and unresponsive. Needless to say that also didn't fix it. I searched every single entry in Regedit for the words "touch" or "type" or anything similar, and none of them yielded anything. I've asked my friends, I've made hundreds of Google searches, I've read 30 forum threads, NOBODY has a solution to this that I can find. Literally everything I've found is for either Synaptics or Elan, aside from the one guy I found who said that my situation is helpless...

So please help me out here guys. I'm out of things to try and my current best option is to just return this PC, which is a real shame because I got a great deal and I'm growing really attached to it... But man, I hate this touchpad driver. (Certainly I'm not the only one facing this?? I hope and pray that somebody else has a solution...)

Comment: Contact the manufacturer technical support people, use a Bluetooth Mouse (I do this), or return the machine.

Comment: I will try contacting technical support. As for the bluetooth mouse, not a solution for me. I have a desktop but I don't do work on it because having to use a mouse makes me extremely unproductive. And is returning the machine really my only other option? I have to think somebody can answer this question...

Comment: @John Also I forgot to mention before. I read that Microsoft is migrating all of its touchpad drivers to be Microsoft Precision Drivers, phasing out Synaptics and Elan for simplicity. If that's the case then returning the laptop my not be a solution if any other device will act exactly the same way....

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer!!!

For people looking for a solution to this in the future, I've got good news, the solution is stupidly simple.

On Windows 11 simply open Touchpad Settings (open Start Menu -> type in "Touchpad" -> click on "Touchpad settings") then open the "Taps" submenu. From there, simply set "Touchpad sensitivity" to "Most sensitive"

And that's it! It's fixed. I have absolutely no idea why or how this fixes it, but it's such a relief to have it working now and I hope this will help a lot of people.

This REALLY needs to be changed to be more clear. There's absolutely no reason why a setting called "Touchpad sensitivity" in a "Taps" menu should dictate whether or not typing locks up your touchpad?? It has nothing to do with taps or sensitivity, and everything to do with typing and touch protection.

Give me back Windows 10 please Microsoft :) I beg you

Comment: Wowwww. This is the first time I actually found an answer that worked. Thank you so much for following up and answering your own question.